# Spam being mailed mentioning Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Today I've received an Email with the following message body:

> Hello,
>
> We are doing a research on duplicate question detection in
>   StackOverflow. Your feedback is very important in our research and it
>   will be highly appreciable if you complete the following survey. It
>   will not take more than 4-5 minutes.
>
> The online survey link is presented as follows: "Duplicate question
>   survey form" (hyperlink removed)
>
> NOTE: Your information and answers will be kept in the strictest
>   confidentiality
>
> If you have any problems or comments, please contact me at any time.
>   Thanks again.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Md. Ahasanuzzaman M.Sc Student, Department of Computer Science and
>   Engineering, University of Dhaka

I know this is most likely fake, but I thought it'd be appropiate to give a heads up about it, as this is the first time in over 2 years I actually receive spam mentioning SO.

EDIT:

I've edited the question due the the misconception that the mail was send in the name of SO. This is clearly not the case. I simply reacted to fast. I didn't delete the question on the advise of [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) just in case other members had questions about it.

Comment: There is nothing here *in the name of StackOverflow*. The fact they mention *StackOverflow* is irrelevant. I can mention "CBS News*, as in "CBS News reported", but that doesn't mean I'm speaking *in the name of CBS News*. You've made an aspersion that is false. Voting to close as such.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree but the question remained open on the advise of a Moderator. It would've been deleted in any other case.

Comment: @KenWhite I've edited the question to make it look more appropriate.

Comment: Where did he get you email address from I wonder?

Comment: @DavidPostill: This particular user's email address is on their profile.

Comment: Not sure why this gets downvoted, I just received the same mail two days ago and have exactly the same question. It's good and legitimate (imo) that some kind of record is kept about correspondence of/from/with/in-the-name-of/for stack-overflow. And since it contains a link to a Google-docs document, people might consider it an honest mail (though I didn't open it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not in the name of SO. Someone is just doing research on the site and on its data. They are in no way representing the site or the company — they're representing their university, as you can see from their signature.

If they were signing off as a representative of SO and/or sending from an address that purported to be from stackoverflow.com, that would be different.

Comment: Ah that seems more likely. Still I thought it was a bit odd. Especially as it triggered my spam filters all over the place. Thanks for explaining though :)

Comment: @icecub: Well it *is* still spam (i.e. unsolicited bulk mail) at any rate - I'd trash it if it didn't wind up in junk first :)

Comment: Ye I'll probebly just delete it. Perhaps I should delete this Meta as well? Or at least remove the link, as it's just more advertisement for them?

Comment: I'd at the very least remove the link (and possibly the sender's name as well), but I'd keep the question on the off chance you're not the only one who received the message and had questions.

Comment: If I wanted to spam/troll SO with robo-duplicate questions, that is the sort of email I would send out.