# Should I complete the survey?

Tags: discussion

I got the following email yesterday...

> Subject: *Outdated and license-violating code snippets on Stack
>   Overflow*
>
> Dear Developer,
>
> Since you are one of the top answerers on Stack Overflow, we hope you
>   can help us with a not-for-profit study.
>
> We are researchers in the Software Systems Engineering Group at
>   University College London, UK. We are studying problems caused by
>   outdated and license-violating code snippets on Stack Overflow.
>
> We have designed a survey to understand these problems and would be
>   grateful if you would complete it:
>
> https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfagOcgFYYqt0vMLZOoacGQ55SeZyhF1g5MTinTBoD23FRktQ/viewform?usp=sf_link
>
> The survey is completely anonymous and has 11 questions and should
>   only take about 3-5 minutes to complete.
>
> The survey results will be used only for academic research purposes
>   and we plan to release the results to Stack Overflow and in the form
>   of academic papers and presentations.
>
> Your email address has been extracted from Stack Overflow and GitHub
>   websites and it will not be saved or distributed to other parties.
>
> This research project has been approved by the designated ethics
>   officer in the Computer Science Department at UCL.
>
> Thank you,
>  Chaiyong Ragkhitwetsagul, Jens Krinke
>  CREST, Dept.
>   of Computer Science
>  University College London
>   www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/C.Ragkhitwetsagul

On top of that why did Stack Overflow share my email address with a third party for any reason without permission?

[Is my email address accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293532/is-my-email-address-accessible)

Comment: *On top of that why SO shared my email address to third party for any reason without permission* They didn't. You put your email address in your profile where it's completely public.

Comment: Some day, I will have enough rep to qualify for email spam like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spam being mailed mentioning Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308236/spam-being-mailed-mentioning-stack-overflow)

Comment: I don't have enough rep but I filled out the survey anyway

Comment: Personally, I looked up the sender and found that he is most likely real and actually studying the topic the mail mentions and the survey is most likely trustworthy. I would not post private information there.

Comment: After filling it out I can report that the survey is on-topic and most likely genuine. It did not ask for personal information and took me between my last comment and now (about 4 minutes). I did not see anything in that survey that could potentially be harmful.

Comment: I can also report that my email contained the exact same link, so there does not seem to be any tracking who answered.

Answer (score 29):

Let's get this out of the way first:

> On top of that why SO shared my email address to third party for any reason without permission?

You shared your email address in your public profile:

[image]

---

Now onto the survey part. It does not seem that this survey is associated with Stack Overflow. I don't see anywhere that this suggests it is endorsed by Stack Overflow. It looks to me like a third party found your profile in a list of profiles matching a given criteria and sent you an invitation to take the survey.

At that point it is up to you whether you want to answer the questions truthfully, if at all. If they asked for anything personally identifying, I would probably close the tab.