# Received emailed survey

Tags: discussion, spam, email, scraping

I received the following email:

> **Subject:** Dear Stack Overflow user, we sincerely invite you to participate_in_an_anonymous_ 
>      survey_about_the_incentive_mechanisms_on_Stack_Overflow [sic]
>
> ---
>
> Thanks so much for your contributions to the Stack Overflow community~
>
> To better understand your motivations and perceptions of participating
>   in the community, we are conducting an anonymous survey. Your
>   participation is confidential, and is expected to take no more than 2
>   minutes.
>
> You can contact us via email: luyao08@nudt.edu.cn. We are looking
>   forward to your response! We sincerely thank you again for providing
>   valuable feedback~
>
> Click the button below to start the survey.

This links to a SurveyMonkey survey. It's unclear; is this something authorised by Stack Overflow? The email address is from [nudt.edu.cn](http://www.nudt.edu.cn/) ([National University of Defense Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_University_of_Defense_Technology)), which would seem unusual for an official survey from Stack Overflow. If not, the email was sent in violation of Canada's anti-spam legislation.

Comment: No, and you’ll notice it sneakily *does not claim* to be from SO or SE, it just thanks you for “contributing to the community”. It’s implied but not stated, so they get the benefit of implied authority but can’t be called out for falsification.

Comment: That's not SO. This isn't the first time something similar has happened either (trying to find previous discussions) - sometimes students consider SO as an appropriate user base for their coursework and try to reach out... (mostly by guessing emails or github links...)

Comment: Related discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353824/should-i-complete-the-survey?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I think this info can be converted into an answer (basically, "nope, not official"), or alternatively this question can be closed. I appreciate the clarifications (and don't appreciate the spammer).

Comment: Should we be scared by the Chinese military having an interest in the effects of gamification?

Comment: @Pekka웃 They already know that the only winning move is not to play.

Comment: I got one of these today, they are still at it. This also worries me as a researcher, as if they are doing this for pure research purposes, they are still illegally obtained the data.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### Update, as 'more than a few' people appear to have received this:

- **This email did not come from Stack Overflow. We are not conducting, condoning, or otherwise affiliated with this survey.**
- ***We did not provide your information to anyone associated with this survey, they probably obtained it by scraping numerous sources on the web (if not your profile directly) and possibly even breached data (Equifax, anyone?) and correlated that to your SO profile.*** This is a clear violation of our ToS and one of the main reasons [that we took some time to update it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa).
- You're free to do what you want, but we recommend ***not*** taking the survey, we have no idea how the data will be used, if it's really anonymous, or if the link even leads to a real survey site.

#### Original answer follows:

---

No, this isn't authorized by us. It's not uncommon for research groups to want to conduct this sort of thing and there's nothing inherently wrong with doing so, but we give them the following guidance when asked:

- Make it *very* clear that you're working independently as a student or professional research team, and how they obtained your contact info (hint: we don't give it to anyone)
- Have a privacy policy posted somewhere very conspicuously and provide links to it
- Make it very clear how the response data will be used, if it will be available to the public, and under what terms

.. and we go on and on a bit depending on the context of how we're asked. But, they didn't ask us, so ...

All I can do is advise you to not participate in the survey as I have no idea what it's for, where the info is going, etc. Just treat it like you would any other unsolicited email and move on.

If you don't have your contact info in your profile, they probably pieced it together from some other data found elsewhere and managed to correlate it, which is equally creepy (we don't share your info), so all the more reason to avoid them.

Comment: Any word yet on what y'all will do about this, if anything? "National University for Defense Technology" (China) suggests they'll probably care very little for a C&D letter

Comment: @Magisch Nothing proactively, what would there be to gain from time spent? The only effort worth putting into something like this is reassuring folks that we had nothing to do with it, which we've done.

Comment: Additional notes: I received this, but my email address was not the same as I use on StackOverflow (and therefore scraped form somewhere else). The link also says "this link is unique to you" (and therefore is conceivably not anonymous).