# How do I report an email about a survey sent to my Stack Overflow email address?

Tags: support, phishing

I've recently received a very suspicious email "thanking me for my contributions to stackoverflow", and requesting that I fill out a survey. Worse still, it's been sent to my actual Stack Overflow email address - and has my Stack Overflow username on it.

If it were a website I'd report it as a phishing scam via [Google's form](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en), but it's an email.

How would I go about reporting such a thing?

Comment: Something similar to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364479/received-emailed-survey?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, that's the exact email I received!

Answer (score 3):

You have lots of information about you posted in [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1460422/starbeamrainbowlabs?tab=profile) that has probably been used to find your e-mail address.

This has nothing to do with Stack Overflow.

Comment: The email address I have registered with stackoverflow is different tot he email address I present anywhere else.

Comment: However it is still quite easily discoverable/guessable.